# FFmpeg concat demuxer not working: No error, and no output

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

**PROBLEM:** 3 identical-format files (all exported in batch together, with identical settings) concatenated using ffmpeg concat demuxer. Command runs without error (and no console printouts either) but also no output file. Mac OS 10.15.6, ffmpeg version 4.3.1

Concat text file "test.txt" as follows:

```
file 'test_clip1.mp4'
file 'test_clip2.mp4'
file 'test_clip3.mp4'
```

Each of these files ffprobe readouts are the same. There is no audio stream.

test_clip1.mp4:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 911 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 19184 tbn, 47.96 tbc (default)
```

test_clip2.mp4

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 628 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 19184 tbn, 47.96 tbc (default)
```

test_clip3.mp4

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 615 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 19184 tbn, 47.96 tbc (default)
```

FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg_cmd = ["ffmpeg",
              "-f",
              "concat",
              "-safe", "0",
              "-i", "test.txt",
              "test_concatenated.mp4"]
```

Comment: Run from console and check.

Comment: @Gyan, thank you! It worked immediately. Turns out this is a real facepalm mistake. I forgot to actually subprocess.call the command itself!

Comment: @dv151 Might as well make that the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Facepalm mistake. I forgot to actually CALL the ffmpeg_cmd in my script with subprocess.call. FF command also worked just fine when called directly from the console. Thank you @Gyan for the tip.